# wxWidgets getting the number of pixels required to display a wxString (single line) - wxDC::GetTextExtent can't be the only way

Tags: c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to get the space required for a string (custom widget stuff - so legitimate use!), it is needed before any draw calls so I haven't got a paint DC (yet) to call http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#ae55cbf1bc7b7e836cb192eb48d31efab on

Now I'd have thought that the space required would be a function of the font, not the DC, but I haven't found a way yet.

I did find some wxPython answers (which isn't a bad thing, the two are easy to switch between!) but they involved getting a DC then calling GetTextExtent on it.

There must be an efficient way!

(I am using wxWidgets 2.8)

Another "answer"

http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=17143&p=74448

It creates a DC also

Another, [The right way to find the size of text in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269880/the-right-way-to-find-the-size-of-text-in-wxpython)

That one creates a wxDC, I can't do that as it is an abstract base class (rightfully so ofc)

Comment: You absolutely need a DC to calculate this, because the answer changes when the DC is attached to a printer vs. a screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `wxClientDC` at any point if you need it just for measurement. And `GetTextExtent()` is the most efficient way to measure a single string. For multiple strings, `GetPartialTextExtents()` can be more useful.